# Child view model in KnockoutJS throws exceptions in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, mvvm, knockout.js

I have something like the following:

```
var ChildViewModel = function (viewModel) {
    // state
    this.viewModel = viewModel;
    this.index = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
        return this.viewModel.selections().indexOf(this);
    }, this);
    this.remove = function () {
        this.viewModel.removeSelection(this);
    };
    this.moveUp = function () {
        this.move(-1);
    };
    this.moveDown = function () {
        this.move(1);
    };
    this.move = function (direction) {
        var i = this.index();
        this.remove();
        this.viewModel.selections.splice(i + direction, 0, this);
    };

    // additional properties

};

var viewModel = {
    selections: ko.observableArray(),
    removeSelection: function (item) {
        this.selections.remove(item);
    },
    addSelection: function (event) {
        var child = new ChildViewModel(this);
        this.selections.push(child );
    }
};

ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

When I call `addSelection`, I have get a `Object doesn't support this property or method` exception inside the KnockoutJS library. My application works fine in Firefox 3.6 and Chrome. I get the exception in IE8. I'm using version 2.0 <strike>1.3 Beta</strike> of KnockoutJS.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you using the minified version of knockout? If so, maybe give the uncompressed version a shot and see what line in knockout is erroring, it might give a clue to a possible cause.

Comment: @AlexKey - i'll update my question.

Comment: @Daniel: My mistake- I did not realize Knockout had an implementation of `indexOf()`.

Comment: Perhaps 'this' isn't bound appropriately in addSelection - do you call addSelection from an element binding? (and if so, what does that binding look like?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok i had 2 different problems.

First, I removed the method to get the value of the array, instead used the observable array.

```
 // Bad code for IE8
 this.viewModel.selections().indexOf(this);

 // this works
 this.viewModel.selections.indexOf(this);
```

Also, I was setting the `for` attribute. IE complains about that `for` is a keyword.

```
// Bad code for IE8
data-bind="attr: { for : logicalOperatorAndFieldId }"

// Good code for IE8
data-bind="attr: { 'for' : logicalOperatorAndFieldId }"
```

Comment: +1, I also had an issue with IE8 claiming `class` was a keyword:  `data-bind="attr: { class: InitialClass }` Using a string instead solved it: `data-bind="attr: { 'class': InitialClass }`

Comment: I just ran into the IE8 issue with `for` in an attr binding.  Saved me a ton of time, so thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Do not use self closing tags like `<span data-bind='text: Text' />`. It also can cause problems in IE8, IE7 when you use knockout.

Comment: this doesn't answer my question.